# Design issues in div height label?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I need to change the div's width depending on the label text's length. Because my label text is cut. Here's [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/elakkiya/pxU55/8/).

Comment: in your jsfiddle, you have your `.left` css styles in the Javascript window

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/elakkiya/pxU55/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `display: inline-block` and clean up the inline styles they were making it difficult to achieve what you wanted. Instead of inline styles it's better if you add those to your css file. [Here's the edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxU55/22/)

Answer (score 0):

The div must be included in label and you must set the position to be relative, `position:relative;`.